# Create another string xml value file in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to have another string.xml in the values folder.

I want to keep the urls in a different file so are not editable. My plan is to have a default url in those files, commit the files and add them to git ignore.

I've tried creating an `url.xml` file in the values folder and add the following items:

```
<resources>
    <item name="device_ip_address" type="string">0.0.0.0</item>
</resources>
```

I tried also with `strings`:

```
<string name="device_ip_address_key" translatable="false">0.0.0.0</string>
```

But when I try to get the string in the `PreferenceScreen` for example, I get a compilation error:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <Preference
        app:key="@string/device_ip_address_key"
        app:title="@string/device_ip_address_title"
        app:summary="@url/device_ip_address"
        app:defaultValue="@url/device_ip_address"
        app:enabled="true"
        />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

or in the activity:

```
val myUrl = getString(R.string.device_ip_address)
```

Any idea how I can achieve this? 
Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?? having that information is kind of needed to help you out because all of your code from the looks of that seems to be fine and you shouldnt have a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried creating an url.xml file in the values folder and add the following items:

This code is perfectly fine. I just added it to a scrap project have no difficulty accessing that resource from another resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/device_ip_address"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

...or from code:

```
package com.commonsware.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val foo = getString(R.string.device_ip_address)
  }
}
```

> But when I try to get the string in the PreferenceScreen for example, I get a compilation error:

There is no `url` resource type. Use `@string/device_ip_address`.

Comment: But is the `device_ip_address` defined in other file than strings.xml? I want to be defined in totally separately file from string.xml.

Comment: @xarly: "But is the device_ip_address defined in other file than strings.xml?" -- yes. I created a `url.xml` file in `res/values/`.

Comment: Wow, I think I've done something wrong in my first code. 
Thanks a lot!